# npm run build produces IE incompatible JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run `npm run build` it produces JavaScript like the following:

```
jQuery.extend({
    propFix: {
        for: "htmlFor",
        class: "className"
    },
```

This can't be interpreted by several versions of IE. It should actually be producing the following:

```
jQuery.extend({
    propFix: {
        "for": "htmlFor",
        "class": "className"
    },
```

Here's my npm / node:

```
$ npm --version
2.14.13
$ node -v
v0.10.40
```

I'm using RHEL6

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "npm i",
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build",
  "local-deploy": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp local-deploy"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.8.10",
  "gulp-coffee": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.4.2",
  "gulp-less": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
  "gulp-template-compile": "^0.2.1",
  "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.5.0",
  "gulp-wrap": "^0.5.0",
  "less-plugin-clean-css": "^1.4.0",
  "underscore": "^1.6.0",
  "yargs": "^1.3.3"
}
```

Comment: Neither Node and npm are responsible for this. What tool are you using that does the actual work?

Comment: I'm using gulp for my build task. Gulp is responsible for running `npm build`

Comment: And what happens when npm build is run? NPM itself is not magically going to change code, there are modules being invoked in your build cycle that do it. That is where it is going wrong.

Comment: I have different environments with checked in node modules that are compiling this differently.

Comment: @Zoidberg: No, it's `npm` that's responsible for running `gulp`, which in turn runs a variety of plugins, *one of which* is stripping the quotes from jQuery's source code (as all versions of jQuery have the quotes on `for` and `class` in the `propFix` object initializer). At a guess, I'd say it could be `gulp-uglify` that's doing it, but really you'll need to debug it to find out what's causing that (or include `jquery.min.js` without passing it through any further minifiers, as it's already minified).

Answer (score -1):

Npm has nothing do with this. The issue will lie with jQuery and your code.

If you are using jQuery 2 or 3, it will not work for IE 6-8.

You can [find all jquery versions here](https://code.jquery.com/).

Also, if you are installing with `npm`, make sure to install an older version of jquery, e.g.:

```
npm install jquery@1.12.4 --save
```